# How can I force overflow on an undefined-size flexbox element in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

The following code works in Chrome perfectly, but not in Firefox. You'll notice that the height of the header, footer, and sidebars are not defined, but the sidebars will still overflow content along the y-axis. This is correct in Chrome 40.0.2214.94 64-bit, but not true in Firefox 35.0.1. What CSS should I apply to this in order to make it work?

Also, if you can't run the below snippet, [here is a CodePen-hosted version](http://s.codepen.io/skulbuny/debug/vEedrV?).

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
header,
footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
header {
  background: tomato;
}
.sidebar-1,
.sidebar-2 {
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-width: 20vw;
}
.content-container {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
}
.sidebar-1 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  -moz-order: 3;
  order: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  background: #afc5cf;
}
.main-content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -moz-order: 2;
  order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}
.sidebar-2 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -moz-order: 1;
  order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  background: #cfafaf;
}
footer {
  background: #bacfaf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content-container">
    <aside class="sidebar-1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
    </aside>
    <aside class="sidebar-2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam ipsa officia, officiis, atque nam nobis aut est odit dolorem quo voluptatibus reprehenderit illum, rerum sint dolores beatae eaque, ea minima!</p>
    </aside>
    <section class="main-content"></section>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <h2>world</h2>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that `.content-container` did not have an overflow property. Adding that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
     overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: or potentially:

    `.container {
           overflow: scroll;
    }`